# Implement an Air API by sending a SOAP request

Tags: php, xml

I have a php web site. Here I need to implement air ticket searching and booking functionality. In order to do this, I have used a paid API from ARZOO web site... I got all the documentation from ARZOO. I have read the entire doc. The Doc Says

```
"Accessing this service requires standard SOAP client. SOAP client should authenticate
itself through user name and password. Client should get their IPs registered with
Arzoo and get a user account created. The Arzoo web service provides a service
point URL. Web service clients should post SOAP request message as an attachment
for the desired response. The XML structure of different web services is discussed in
the respective documents." 
You can connect to Arzoo XML services with the following test service point URLs:-

FlightAvailability:http://<url>/DOMFlightAvailability?wsdl
```

I think need to send the request via soap is it? 
But in the air availability contains

```
Example Request Xml
<Request>
<Origin>BOM</Origin>
.............
.............
</Request>
```

I have used the following code

```
$post_string.="<Request>";
$post_string.="<Origin>$from</Origin><Destination>$to</Destination>";
........
......

$post_string.="</Request>";
$path = ":http://<url>/DOMFlightAvailability?wsdl"; 

$ch = curl_init($path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); //Send the data to the file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
$val = curl_exec($ch);
 $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
 $errr=curl_error($ch);
```

But it's not giving any result.
The documents says

```
RESPONSE XML:-
The response will be in <arzoo_response> </arzoo_response>. This contains the Request
also.
```

I don't know SOAP.

I am totally disappointed. Please Help me.
I think I will get an xml response after posting the request. But how I will post my data?

Please reply

Many thanks, if anyone help me, its great appreciable

Answer (score 4):

i also getting error while using SOAP CLIENT but when i use nusoap then they give me result..using this code if u get error like ip/password mismatch then You will call arzoo to verify your clientid and clientpassword

```
    <?php
  ini_set('max_execution_time','180');
    include 'lib/nusoap.php';
   $location_URL ='http://avail.flight.arzoo.com';
   $action_URL ='http://demo.arzoo.com/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightAvailability?wsdl';
$Request = '<Request>
<Origin>BOM</Origin>
<Destination>DEL</Destination>
<DepartDate>2017-02-02</DepartDate>
<ReturnDate>2017-02-02</ReturnDate>
<AdultPax>1</AdultPax>
<ChildPax>0</ChildPax>
<InfantPax>0</InfantPax>
<Currency>INR</Currency>
<Clientid>Given by Arzoo.com</Clientid>
<Clientpassword>Given by Arzoo.com</Clientpassword>
<Clienttype>ArzooFWS1.1</Clienttype>
<Preferredclass>E</Preferredclass>
<mode>ONE</mode>
<PreferredAirline>AI</PreferredAirline>
</Request>';

$clientinfo = array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
'location' =>$location_URL,
'uri' =>$action_URL,
 'style' => SOAP_RPC,
 'use' => SOAP_ENCODED,
 'trace' => 1,
 );

 $client = new nusoap_client('http://demo.arzoo.com/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightAvailability?wsdl', $clientinfo);
//print_r($client);
$result = $client->call('getAvailability', array($Request));
echo"<pre>";
print_r($result);
$clientInfo =simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode($result));
$flight = $clientInfo->Response__Depart->OriginDestinationOptions->OriginDestinationOption;
$error =$clientInfo->error__tag;
//echo $error;
var_dump($flight);
//exit;
//echo"<pre>";
//print_r($result);
//ECHO $error;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since they are mentioned `standard SOAP client` and you are sending the cURL request to the Server that will never give any response.

```
$location_URL = "http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightAvailability";
$action_URL ="http://com.arzoo.flight.avail";

$client = new SoapClient('http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightAvailability?wsdl', array(
'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
'location' => $location_URL,
'uri'      => $action_URL,
'style'    => SOAP_RPC,
'use'      => SOAP_ENCODED,
'trace'    => 1,
));

try
{
    $result = $client->__call('getAvailability',array($req_int));
    $response= htmlentities($result);
}
```

You can use SOAP1.1 Request.