# getting data from SOAP request in php

Tags: php, soap

I have a php web site.Here i need to implement flight searching functionality and booking features.i have used paid API from arzoo,but i can't get the response also i am new to SOAP concepts.here is my code

```
$input_xml = '<AvailRequest>
            <Trip>ONE</Trip>
            <Origin>BOM</Origin>
            <Destination>JFK</Destination>
            <DepartDate>2013-09-15</DepartDate>
            <ReturnDate>2013-09-16</ReturnDate>
            <AdultPax>1</AdultPax>
            <ChildPax>0</ChildPax>
            <InfantPax>0</InfantPax>
            <Currency>INR</Currency>
            <PreferredClass>E</PreferredClass>
            <Eticket>true</Eticket>
            <Clientid>xxx</Clientid>
            <Clientpassword>xxxx</Clientpassword>
            <Clienttype>xxx</Clienttype>
            <PreferredAirline>AI</PreferredAirline>
    </AvailRequest>';

$client = new SoapClient('http://59.162.33.102/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightAvailability?wsdl');
 $result = $client->__call('getAvailability',array($input_xml));
```

the output of `$result` is `invalid xml format`.Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Please carefully read [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481557/implement-an-air-api-by-sending-a-soap-request) which discusses your problem.  I was able to access the WSDL from the URL in your code, and I verified that the SOAP service is up and running using SOAP UI.

Comment: Ii read that, from this `$client->__call('getAvailability',array($req_int))` what is `$req_int`. it is the array of params?

Comment: The second parameter to `__call()` should be an array of keys and values, so e.g. `array($req_int) = array('Trip'=>'ONE', 'Origin'=>'BOM', ...)`

Comment: get new error `[VersionMismatch] `