# soap request and response in php LARAVEL

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

i am new to soap request and response in PHP ,i am working with recharge API.
API providers given me below XML(I Am using Arzoo API Providers).

```
<MobileRechargeRequest>
  <Clientid>Given By Arzoo</Clientid>
 <Clientpassword>Given By Arzoo</Clientpassword>
<ClientType>ArzooFWS1.1</ClientType>
<ServiceProvider>AIRTEL-TopUp</ServiceProvider>
<ServiceProviderId>1</ServiceProviderId>
<Rechrgeamount>100.0</Rechrgeamount>
<SubscriberID>9876543210</SubscriberID>
<PartnerReferenceId>123456</PartnerReferenceId>
</MobileRechargeRequest>
```

They said this is SOAP API, how can i send this request to their URL:-

```
http://demo.arzoo.com/ArzooWS/services/MobileRecharge?wsdl
```

using SOAP in PHP.
I tried like below code

```
 $soapclient = new \SoapClient('http://demo.arzoo.com/ArzooWS/services/MobileRecharge?wsdl');

    //Use the functions of the client, the params of the function are in 
    //the associative array
    $params = array('CountryName' => 'Spain', 'CityName' => 'Alicante');
    $response = $soapclient->getMobileDetails('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
        <soap:Body>

        <getMobileDetails xmlns="http://demo.arzoo.com/ArzooWS/services/MobileRecharge">
        <MobileRechargeRequest>
                        <Clientid>77743781</Clientid>
                         <Clientpassword>******</Clientpassword>
                         <Clienttype>ArzooFWS1.1</Clienttype>
                        <ServiceProvider>AIRTEL-TopUp</ServiceProvider>
                        <ServiceProviderId>1</ServiceProviderId>
                        <Rechrgeamount>100.0</Rechrgeamount>
                        <SubscriberID>9164995714</SubscriberID>
                        <PartnerReferenceId>123456</PartnerReferenceId>
                 </MobileRechargeRequest>  </getMobileDetails> </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>');

    var_dump($response);
```

I am not getting any response please help me , if i have error in SOAP XML request

Comment: hi please help me ,i am waiting for all your support.

Comment: Not something I've used, but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481557/implement-an-air-api-by-sending-a-soap-request it may help.

Comment: @NigelRen , i tried above code , it helped me a lot, i am sending now data to url, but i am getting null response.