# How to Generate XML With "wsse" Header

Tags: xml, asp.net-core

we are using asp Core to generate XML Code to be sent to our WSDL Provider,
you can check the sample below that we manually wrote it, and its working just fine when we are trying to form the PostMan, so  we tried to generate the XML programmatically, we got the same XML But some tags missed like "wsse", please do check the sample below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="XXXX">
            <wsse:Username>XXX</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXX</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body xmlns:ns1="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
      <ns1:OTA_AirAvailRQ EchoToken="11868765275150-1300257933" PrimaryLangID="en-us" SequenceNmbr="1" TimeStamp="2012-08-27T03:00:23" Version="20061.00" Target="TEST">
         <ns1:POS>
            <ns1:Source TerminalID="XXXX">
               <ns1:RequestorID ID="XXXX" Type="XXXX" />
               <ns1:BookingChannel Type="12" />
            </ns1:Source>
         </ns1:POS>
         <ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>
            <ns1:DepartureDateTime WindowAfter="P1D" WindowBefore="P1D">2023-01-20T10:00:00</ns1:DepartureDateTime>
            <ns1:OriginLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
            <ns1:DestinationLocation LocationCode="SHJ" />
         </ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>
         <ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>
            <ns1:DepartureDateTime WindowAfter="P1D" WindowBefore="P1D">2023-01-25T10:00:00</ns1:DepartureDateTime>
            <ns1:OriginLocation LocationCode="SHJ" />
            <ns1:DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
         </ns1:OriginDestinationInformation>
         <ns1:TravelerInfoSummary>
            <ns1:AirTravelerAvail>
               <ns1:PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="3" />
               <ns1:PassengerTypeQuantity Code="CHD" Quantity="1" />
            </ns1:AirTravelerAvail>
         </ns1:TravelerInfoSummary>
      </ns1:OTA_AirAvailRQ>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but when we are trying to generate it we getting this sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <Header>
        <Security mustUnderstand="1" wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <UsernameToken Id="xxx" wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xs">
                <Username>xx</Username>
                <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxx</Password>
            </UsernameToken>
        </Security>
    </Header>
    <Body ns2="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <OTA_AirAvailRQ EchoToken="11868765275150-1300257933" PrimaryLangID="en-us" SequenceNmbr="1" Target="xx" TimeStamp="2023-01-14T12:01:53.3258485+03:00" Version="20061">
            <POS>
                <Source TerminalID="xx">
                    <RequestorID ID="xx" Type="4" />
                    <BookingChannel Type="12" />
                </Source>
            </POS>
            <OriginDestinationInformation>
                <DepartureDateTime WindowAfter="P1D" WindowBefore="P1D">2023-01-20T10:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="BOM" />
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="SHJ" />
            </OriginDestinationInformation>
            <TravelerInfoSummary>
                <AirTravelerAvail>
                    <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
                </AirTravelerAvail>
            </TravelerInfoSummary>
        </OTA_AirAvailRQ>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

So Can you please let us know how we can generate the XML With these "wsse" tags?

My First Attempt with the code was this and I am getting this error from it "Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported" , we are trying with ASP CORE Web API 3.1

```
            System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding binding =
            new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            binding.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            binding.AllowCookies = true;
            binding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            binding.TransferMode = System.ServiceModel.TransferMode.Buffered;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
            ServiceHelper _ServiceHelper = new ServiceHelper();
            var address = new EndpointAddress("https://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices");
            var client = new AAResWebServicesClient((Binding)binding, address);

            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _ServiceHelper.airarabia9GUserName;
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _ServiceHelper.airarabia9Gpassword;
            OTA_AirAvailRQ test = new OTA_AirAvailRQ();
            OTA_AirAvailRS TEST2;
            try
            {
                var httpHeaders = ReturnHttpHeader(_ServiceHelper.airarabia9GUserName, _ServiceHelper.airarabia9Gpassword);
                client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new HttpHeadersEndpointBehavior(httpHeaders));
                //  TEST2 = client.getAvailability (test);
                TEST2 = client.getAvailability(test);
            }
            catch (Exception se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error : " + se.Message);
                client.Abort();
                return null;
            }
```

and my second attempt with the code is that I created the Modules manually based on the Samples and try to convert them into  XML But also failed which I think this is wrong oprtion from the first place

```
//envelope Containt all the modules and will convert them into XML
            var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope),
                             "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05");
            serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, envelope);
            string strXML = stringwriter.ToString();
            strXML = strXML.Replace("utf-16", "utf-8");

            var url = _Helper.airarabia9GURL;
            var client2 = new RestClient(url);
            var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST);



            #region Headers
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            request.AddHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=0F63BEC1C68DDEC6ADB581CC621E1B8E.demo2144");

            #endregion


            request.AddParameter("application/xml", Mybody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client2.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

FYI: We are using the same project to integrate different API Like Travelport ,  Turkish ,  QR  AirLine etc and they are working fine

Comment: That's not XML with a wsse prefix. That's a SOAP request using the Web Service Extensions standards. That's where the `wsse` namespace from. WSE specifies several *behaviors*, not just schemas, like authentication, authorization, transactions etc. WCF and in .NET Core, CoreWCF implement several WS extensions automatically

Comment: I work for a big OTA too. You don't generate SOAP requests and responses by hand, you generate classes and clients from a service's WSDL (service description) and XSD (XML schema) documents. You can generate a client and DTOs automatically from a WSDL with the `svcutil` tool, or by adding a Connected Service reference in Visual Studio. GDSs and airlines make this harder than it has to be because the requests are huge and some of them publish WSDL and XSD files as documentation, not an endpoint you can use in Visual Studio or svcutil

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have already worked with multiple GDSs Like Travelport and we added their WSDL  from WFC In visual studio It actually worked, but for this airline, we got an error message when we were trying to add it as WFC From Visual Studio, so I tried with svcutil tool and Schema generated, 
but when I tried to use same Travelport code with this airline got also an error message especially since this airline doesn't have any sample code that I can use
@PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: This is the Code that iam trying to use but also getting error message with it 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jDpn-icXUc9i7sKHSeG5PG79ZcK__8ok/view?usp=sharing

error message "Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported"
@PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Post the code in the question. This has nothing to do with adding prefixes, and the error certainly has nothing to do with XML. Where did this come from? This looks like an attempt to reconstruct what WCF would generate automatically. Someone already constructed the DTOs from the XSD so the prefixes should be added automatically.

Comment: Where did you try to run this code? The error `Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported` appears in [.NET Core 3.1 SOAP platform not supported error "Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60976792/net-core-3-1-soap-platform-not-supported-error-compiling-jscript-csharp-script) too. That was due to a bug in .NET Core 3.1, which is no longer supported. Actual WCF support is provided by the [Core WCF project](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF).

Comment: I suspect someone tried to convert .NET Framework WCF code into .NET Core? And when that failed, they tried to build the proxy by hand? That doesn't work because the incompatibilities are inside the WCF classes themselves, not their APIs or the generated proxies.

Comment: **Again, post the code**. It's extremely important, and I can't google for type names from an image. It's quite possible Air Arabia has a WSDL endpoint you can test with `Core WCF` right now. [From similar SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481557/implement-an-air-api-by-sending-a-soap-request/) I see they do have demo endpoints. Can you post the one for `OTA_AirAvailRQ` ?

Comment: PS: `Add Service Reference` in a .NET 6 project in Visual Studio 2022 should probably work too. There were a lot of changes since .NET Core 3

Comment: I tried to add a service reference to `https://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices` and see it kind-of-works because the OpenTravel URLs aren't real URLs. Is that the reason you tried to call the internal classes by hand? In that case you need to download the WSDL and XSDs locally, and add a `Service Reference` by loading those files explicitly

Comment: thanks for your amazing support,  
and yes I am using asp core 3.1 and I am not sure if we can upgrade right now, especially since this project is connected to multiple APIs,  
And yes when trying to add it as WFC Reference I got error message, @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: also, I Have added the code in the question that I am trying to work on it you can review it if you want, 
but you're saying that I need to download the WSDL locally  how can I download it and add it locally if the WSDL Provider sending us only these links 

https://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl
https://airarabia3l.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?
@PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: You can't *not* upgrade to .NET 6. .NET Core 3.1 reached End-of-Life last year, and library authors have already started removing support for this.

Comment: and this is the demo endpoint "https://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices"
which  we are using for the OTA_AirAvailRQ
@PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: As for the WSDL, I just tried to add a service reference and remembered the joys of working with airline services. I used `svcutil http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl` to generate a WCF client in the end. Notice it's `http://`, not `https://`. Now I remembered why you need to specify the bindings this way.

Comment: Yea I used this 
svcutil http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl
and Proxy code Generated,  but still can't even send one successful request, for air Arabia, its working great for Travelport,  
so in your point of view, is the issue with my code or something else 
@PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0):

`wsse` is a namespace prefix to the element name. The prefix is "bound"/defined/identified via `xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"`. I don't know what code was written to produce the "incomplete"/undesired current XML output, but can imagine you can use some method or option to create elements with namespace declarations and elements with a bound namespace prefix to them. Maybe `System.Xml.XmlDocument.CreateElement(String, String)` or `System.Xml.XmlDocument.CreateElement(String, String, String)` of .NET (the overloaded variants with 2/3 `String` parameters). But I'm just guessing.

Comment: I have attached the code, you can check  dear If you want

Comment: @Yousif Thanks a lot! Clarifies you're using serialization, not constructing the elements manually. Meanwhile, Tiny Wang provided an answer, which is likely correct: adding `XmlSerializerNamespaces` to `XmlSerializer.Serialize()` (overloaded with 3 parameters). Also, the `[XmlElement()]` annotations for namespace might be necessary for your `Envelope` class (but `Envelope` might be a standard class which already has such an annotation, and just the mapping/declaration of the desired prefix is missing for the serializer). I can't test, but seems Tiny Wang had some success with this method.

Answer (score 0):

I had a test with code below,

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync() {
    UserModel user = new UserModel();
    user.userName = "user1";
    user.Password = "pwd";
    
    var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");
    ns.Add("wsse", "http://aa.com");
    ns.Add("bbb", "http://bb.com");

    var ser = new XmlSerializer(user.GetType());
    var res = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    ser.Serialize(res, user, ns);
    return new ContentResult
    {
        Content = res.ToString(),
        ContentType = "application/xml",
        StatusCode = 200
    };
}

namespace WebApi.Models
{
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://bb.com")]
    public class UserModel
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://aa.com")]
        public string? userName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://aa.com")]
        public string? Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the test result is, the node which defined the same `Namespace` will be added the prefix.

[image]

Comment: The question asks about a SOAP *request*, not a Web API response. Generating temporary strings like this is a really bad idea and completely inappropriate in web service scenarios, especially high volume ones

Comment: let's wait for OP's response. and you can provide your own solution or demo. that's ok.

Comment: There's nothing to wait for. That's a SOAP request, not a response. WCF works this way, ASMX Web Services work this way. That's what a WCF client sends, not what it receives. And, btw, I work for an online agency and had to deal with that specific call in the past. The *actual* requests are 15-10 times larger

Comment: As for serializing to string, that's a bad idea for JSON, XML or any other format. This allocates yet another a copy of the data that needs to be garbage-collected. That's why we don't serialize objects to strings before returning them in Web APIs or posting them with HttpClient, why we use JsonContent. The Json formatter serializes them directly to the output stream to avoid double and triple buffering

Comment: it sounds great. could you pls post a sample for the good performance?

Comment: Yes, create a WCF proxy from the WSDL file and call the method. Let the proxy do the serialization. WCF uses buffer pooling to eliminate allocations as much as possible, caches type and serialization metadata so it doesn't have to rebuild it on any call *and* allows asynchronous operations.